# how to retrieve query parameters from login vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to make an app where customers sit in a restaurant, and the table have QR code that leads to the site http://localhost:8080/login?table=3  when customers log in I want to get the number of the table that he is sitting.

If there is a restaurant with qr code on every table http://localhost:8080/login?table=1, http://localhost:8080/login?table=2, etc. When customer scan qr code and log in i want to know on what table hes sitting so when he orders bartender will know where to bring that order. I want to retrieve that table number after the log in.
loginOverlay.addLoginListener(event -> {
try {
boolean check = new DataBaseAccess().verificationCustomer(event.getUsername(), event.getPassword());
if (check) {
String tableNumber= How to get table number from url (http://localhost:8080/login?table=1);
Customer customer= new Customer(tableId, event.getUsername(), . . . )

Comment: Have you tried https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/additional-guides/query-parameters

Comment: It works with beforeEnter but i want to extract username from login check if its in DB and then make new object in java with that table

Comment: The beforeEnter event is happening before the addLoginListener, so you can remember the table. Buf if you already have tried things, then please add the code to the question so we can see the actual problem.

Comment: Note, you can process query parameters also in afterNavigation also, you are likely to be in middle of navigation, so you actually have to.